# How to avoid redeclaration of constants in python 3

Tags: python, constants, redeclaration

We have a file, where we have constant definitions and there are a lot of them. When there is a name collision, python assigns a new value to it without warning that constant with such name already exists. This is a potential source of bugs. Static code analyzers we use did not find it (Sonarqube and pylint). How to make sure that there are no name collisions?

PS: PyCharm raises "Redeclared defined above without usage", but I don't use PyCharm.

Comment: For python 3.8+, you can use [`typing.Final`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final).

Comment: Use a [Singleton](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html)? Actually probably easier/better if you make all your constants members of a class or dictionary. For example `myconstants.x` or `constdict["x"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olvin Roght said use typing.Final

```
from typing import Final
MAX_SIZE: Final = 9000
MAX_SIZE += 1 # Error reported by type checker
```

Note that this will return an error in your type checker but the code would still run and the value would still change.

This requires Python 3.8+

---

Alternatively you can do:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Consts:
  MAX_SIZE = 9000
myconsts = Consts()
myconsts.MAX_SIZE= 1 # generates an error
```

Comment: The first approach is correct for me. What I want is not to be able to have two variables with the same name in the same class, having it frozen is useful too though. Unfortunately we use python 3.6.5.